# firefox build UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, firefox, encoding, build

Im trying to build Firefox from source on a Debian Linux distro. I installed all prerequierenments with the bootstrap.py script and downloaded the source via mercurial.

Now when i run: ./mach build
i got this encoding error..

```
./mach build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mach", line 55, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "./mach", line 27, in main
    mozinfo_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'mozinfo.json')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i fix this encoding issue? Im not very familiar with linux so i have really no idea. Sadly there is no similar issue found on the internet :/

Comment: What is the path of your current working directory?

Comment: /home/max/Arbeitsfläche/Firefox/mozilla-central/

I think its because of the 'ä', im trying it from /home/max/mozilla-central/ now...

Okay tried it now from there and it worked! thanks for the help.